# error on using boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using a pre-build 1.66 (lib32-msvc-14.0) that I've downloaded. I'm using Visual studio 2015.
I could run a sample without problem. 
But in my project as soon as I include it( a simle wrapper), it generates a lot of errors.

here's my simple wrapper:

Net.h :

```
#ifndef _PCNET_h
#define _PCNET_h

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef void(*newDataCallbackPtr)(byte cmd, byte *data, int len);

namespace net {

    void init(std::string host, std::string port);

    void send(byte cmd, byte *data, int len);

    void registerCB(newDataCallbackPtr cb);

    void join();
}

#endif
```

Net.cpp :

```
#include "Net.h"

const int max_length = 66000;
tcp::socket *s;
std::string delim = ";z|";
std::string recvData;
std::thread *t, *t2;
newDataCallbackPtr CB;

void readThrd();
//Public
void net::init(std::string host, std::string port) {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    s = new tcp::socket(io_context);
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
    boost::asio::connect(*s, resolver.resolve(host, port));

    t = new std::thread([&io_context]() { io_context.run(); });
    t2 = new std::thread(readThrd);

}

void net::send(byte cmd, byte *data, int len) {
    byte *buff = new byte[len + 4];
    buff[0] = cmd;
    memcpy(buff + 1, data, len);
    buff[len + 1] = ';';
    buff[len + 2] = 'z';
    buff[len + 3] = '|';
    boost::asio::write(*s, boost::asio::buffer(buff, len + 4));
    delete[] buff;
}

void net::registerCB(newDataCallbackPtr cb) {
    CB = cb;
}

void net::join() {
    t->join();
}
//Prv8

void readThrd() {
    while (true)
    {
        size_t n = boost::asio::read_until(*s, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(recvData), delim);

        byte *buff = new byte[n - 3];
        memcpy(buff, recvData.c_str(), n - 3);
        recvData.erase(0, n);
        CB(buff[0], buff + 1, (int)n - 4);
    }
}
```

the rest of my project compiles without any problem. but as soon as i Include this Net.h (in another .cpp), compilers gives me a lot of errors in winuser and asio headers:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: pcMode, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  PCutil.cpp
1>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winuser.h(5836): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of 'tagINPUT' when no variable is declared
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winuser.h(5836): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winuser.h(5836): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winuser.h(5843): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPINPUT'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(74): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(74): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(75): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(76): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(44): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(76): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(76): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(82): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(82): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(83): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(84): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(44): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(84): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(84): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(90): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(90): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(91): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(92): error C2974: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type': invalid template argument for 'T', type expected
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(44): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(92): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(92): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(98): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(98): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(99): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(100): error C2974: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type': invalid template argument for 'T', type expected
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(44): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_result_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(100): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(100): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): warning C4544: '<unnamed-symbol>': default template argument ignored on this template declaration
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(108): note: see declaration of '<unnamed-symbol>'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(118): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(118): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(119): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(120): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(120): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(120): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(124): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(124): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(125): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(126): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(126): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(126): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(134): warning C4544: '<unnamed-symbol>': default template argument ignored on this template declaration
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(133): note: see declaration of '<unnamed-symbol>'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(144): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(144): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(145): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(146): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(146): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(146): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(151): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(151): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(152): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(153): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(153): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(153): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(219): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type'
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(493): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::asio::executor_binder<T,Executor>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(219): error C2955: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type': use of class template requires template argument list
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_type'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(220): error C2976: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_types': too few template arguments
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(134): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_types'
1>c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(220): error C2955: 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_types': use of class template requires template argument list
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost\asio\bind_executor.hpp(134): note: see declaration of 'boost::asio::detail::executor_binder_argument_types'
1>  Net.cpp
1>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

as for PCutil. it has a lot of codes, I've removed irrelevant parts. here's the related parts:
PCutil.h:

```
#ifndef _PCUTIL_h
#define _PCUTIL_h

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "pinNameDef.h"

extern int ardDigitalPin2PinNum[];


#define HIGH 1
#define OUTPUT 1
#define LOW 0
#define INPUT 0

typedef unsigned char byte;


extern byte exE2PR[];
extern byte inE2PR[];

void PCSend(NETCMDS id, int len, byte b1 = 0, byte b2 = 0, byte b3 = 0, byte b4 = 0, byte b5 = 0, byte b6 = 0, byte b7 = 0, byte b8 = 0);
void PCSend(NETCMDS id, int len, byte *data);


void init(char* host, char* port);
void joinNet();

#endif
```

PCutil.cpp

```
#include "PCutil.h"
#include "pinNameDef.h"
#include "../spec.h"
#include "../config.h"
#include "Net.h"

byte exE2PR[PCE2PRSIZE];
byte inE2PR[PCE2PRSIZE];

void PCSend(NETCMDS id, int len, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4, byte b5, byte b6, byte b7, byte b8) {
    byte b[] = { b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8 };
    net::send(id, b, len + 1);
}
void PCSend(NETCMDS id, int len, byte *data) {
    net::send(id, data, len);
}


void netCB(byte cmd, byte *data, int len) {
    //some codes
}

void init(char* host, char* port) {
    Net init
    net::registerCB(netCB);
    net::init(host, port);
}
void joinNet() {
    net::join();
}
```

any idea whats wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried what the error proposed? Define your target OS version https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I thought the error message was very clear `Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.`

Comment: @A.A : I did it right now. didnt fix the errors, just that first warning.

Comment: What did you define it as? What is your target? It's like getting blood from a stone.

Comment: -__-  I added '/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 ' in additional options

Comment: Compiler messages are from PCutil.cpp, and you show here Net.cpp. Post relevant information to find an error, with fill list of #include lines in the beginning of cpp file.

Comment: PCutil is too big so i emitted that. I'll add a summery.

Comment: Try moving the C includes after boost. Looks like there are some defines mIxing up. Do you have any `#define INPUT` or `FAR` or `PINPUT`?

Comment: I'm no expert but '/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 means Windows 7 but your windows kit is 8.1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1

Comment: @A.A : Yes. I have a 'INPUT' macro ( And I need that, can't rename it)

Comment: Why not use nugget to download boost-vc140?

Comment: @john: microsoft said 'Minimum system required' so i put win7 there. changed it to win 8.1, still got those errors.

Comment: @falopsy: whats the difference? it seems I've configured compiler & linker correctly.

Comment: @ajlajlajl you'll have to `#undef` it for the boost inlcude, windows also has it `typedef struct tagINPUT {...} INPUT,` Or somehow reduce the scope of this define by moving it somewhere else.

Comment: Ask a specific question. "I need a macro that conflicts with third party headers, how do I solve this?"

Comment: Yeah all the errors was for name conflicts, I have INPUT , A0,A1,A2 . they all conflict with asio...